# Customise table view cell in Mac app

Tags: cocoa

Am trying to customise a table view cell. I have created a separate nib file for the cell. Have added a Table view Cell in it with the customised layout ( 2 textfields and an image). All of them have an outlet.

In,

```
- (NSView *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView viewForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    MyCell *myCell = [tableView makeViewWithIdentifier:@"cellId" owner:self];
    myCell.text1.stringValue = @"Foo";
    myCell.text2.stringValue = @"Bar";
    return myCell;
}
```

I know this is wrong implementation, but how can I load a new nib for a cell in a tableView ?

Comment: Why are you using nib for a cell? Subclass NSTextFieldCell.

Comment: @ParagBafna I needed a custom layout for cell. I was trying to follow this for Mac http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using

```
- (void)registerNib:(NSNib *)nib forIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
```

to register your cell xibs?